# How to handle Screen rotation of activity which have more data?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have one activity which has more than 20 fields, most of these fields will prompt user to set data.

Now the problem with the Configuration changes. If user set all the fields & he/she changed screen orientation, then all the fields will be reset because the activity will restart.

If I have only few fields means, then I would have gone with onSaveInstanceState() & onRestoreInstanceState().

But how to handle these many fields? Whether I have to go by storing all the fields? or Is there any better approach?

Comment: you can set onConfigchanges attribute in mainfest.xml to stop activity from reloading

Comment: Why is 20 fields any different from 2 fields? What I do is store my UI data in a container object and then I pass that container to onSaveInstanceState(). I need to handle only one direct object reference no matter how much data I have in the container.

Comment: This link will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049519/edittext-data-is-lost-on-rotating-the-device

Comment: @Torben getting & setting 20 fields wont be heavy for thread? Now I have only 20, but think if you have hundreds of fields.

Comment: 20 fields is nothing at all. You shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Ricardo - ya I agree with you but I posted to know better approach other than OnSavedInstance & modelObject

Answer (score 1):

add   `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to activity tag in manifest file but that is not best way please read [Why not use always android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation) and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html for selecting best way for yourself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable) is a good example for using from parcle .

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config.that help you

Comment: Thanks Zohreh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation link is very good

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can prevent the activity from rotating to avoid the problem, this should only be done in special circumstances. Also, there are other situations where configuration changes can take place and cause problems. For a full discussion, see this: [Why not use always android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation)

So my suggestion is that instead you create a holder class that implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Then on `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` simply call `outState.putParcelable(key, yourParcelableObject)`. You would still need to update the corresponding fields on and this class but at least you would avoid having several keys and calling individual `put` to the bundle.